# How to position a div next to the right bottom of a table in a modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a modal and inside the modal content I have got a table and a div section to show some information about the table. I would like to position the div section next to the right bottom of the table. I tried setting the div to fixed position and then giving it bottom zero but that will result in placing the div in the footer of the modal. How can I add The div next to bottom right of the table. I don't mind in smaller screen size for the div to be at the right bottom of the table where the table takes the full width. attached Image is what I would like to achieve.
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table id="items-job-payments-modal-table" class="table table-striped">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Date</th>
                           <th>Amount</th>
                           <th>Type</th>
                           <th>Note</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Example</td>
                           <td>Example</td>
                           <td>Example</td>
                           <td>Example</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label id="">Total Cost</label>
                     <label id="">10</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label id="">Balance</label>
                     <label id="">5</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used class "align-self-end" which is a predefined class available in bootstrap 4. Below is the fix.
**Please check this result in full view mode.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
     
   </head>
    
   <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                   <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table id="items-job-payments-modal-table" class="table table-striped">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th>Date</th>
                               <th>Amount</th>
                               <th>Type</th>
                               <th>Note</th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                            <tr>
                               <td>Example</td>
                               <td>Example</td>
                               <td>Example</td>
                               <td>Example</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                               <td>Example1</td>
                               <td>Example1</td>
                               <td>Example1</td>
                               <td>Example1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                               <td>Example2</td>
                               <td>Example2</td>
                               <td>Example2</td>
                               <td>Example2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                               <td>Example3</td>
                               <td>Example3</td>
                               <td>Example3</td>
                               <td>Example3</td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                      </table>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 align-self-end">
                    <div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label id="">Total Cost</label>
                     <label id="">10</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label id="">Balance</label>
                     <label id="">5</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: On mobile size can we pull the div to the right. can you help me do that. Do I need to use media queries ?

Comment: Hi, are you using bootstrap framework so media queries is not required. You can use bootstrap class to make it responsive.  You can change the class name in your above code.  
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 align-self-end"></div>